# Show specific content based on form field value (email address domain)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, css

I have an ajax signup form that uses jQuery and CSS3.

It is multi-step, in step 1 asking for e-mail address and password.

I want to take the domain of the e-mail address and tailor the next step of the form showing different content. There is only one domain I want to single out for specific content, for example;

- Special Option 1

All other domains (gmail, live, hotmail etc...) should be shown general options, with the singled out domain's content not showing at all, for example;

- General Option 1
- General Option 2
- General Option 3

I have created the code below but it does not appear to be working at all, all of my element references are correct but it just isn't triggering.

```
var idx = emailaddress.lastIndexOf('@');
if (idx > -1 && emailaddress.slice(idx) === 'premiumcars.co.uk') 
{ function swap(special, general) {
document.getElementById(special).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(general).style.display = 'none';
}}
```

My concept was that the general content would be in a general div element and special content in a special div element using the javascript function to first determine the domain then swap the elements.

Comment: What you do here is "if email address ends with 'premiumcars.co.uk', define a function 'swap'". Do you want to just define it here, or you wanted to call it?

Comment: I want to call it and show only the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var idx = emailaddress.lastIndexOf('@');
if (idx > -1 && emailaddress.slice(idx) === 'premiumcars.co.uk'){
    document.getElementById(special).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(general).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Don't make a function, just do what you want, directly in `if` statement.

EDIT: This is a fiddle that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/81r0qenv/

Comment: Still doesn't appear to be working. I've created some dummy divs in a js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/235vmr46/

Comment: I've edited my post, there's a fiddle that works what you want, but it seems that you have some serious gaps in Javascript and DOM knowledge. Try some of the online courses, they will help you know what you're doing, and what to ask when you have a problem.